# Neo4j - minimum value from array properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How do I get with cypher the minimum value of array with properties?

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) RETURN n,m,min(r.timestamps)
```

Above query does not work.

`r`  has an array with timestamps `r.timestamps`
How to get the lowest value of timestamps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [unwind](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-unwind.html):

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
UNWIND r.timestamps as timestampts
RETURN n, m, min(timestampts)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer like this, but it looks ugly

```
MATCH 
    (h1)-[r]-(h2) 
RETURN h1, h2, 
    reduce(minTimestamp = 999999999999999999, t IN r.timestamps | CASE WHEN minTimestamp < t THEN minTimestamp ELSE t END)
```